# Need Help in Deriving a Combinatorial Formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $S$ be the set of all $n$-permutations of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. An element in $S$ (an ordered $n$-tuple) satisfies the property $P_k$ if $k$ is followed immediately by $k + 1$, where $1 \le k \le n-1$. Let $C_i$ be the number of elements in $S$ which satisfy at least $i$ properties, where $0 \le i \le n-1$. How do I derive a formula for $C_i$?

The given answer is $\binom{n-1}{i}(n - i)!$. I only know that $\binom{n-1}{i}$ gives the number of ways to choose $i$ out of $n-1$ properties to be satisfied. But I'm not sure how $(n - i)!$ was derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in this way: For each number we choose, there is one extra number where the position becomes fixed (it must come immediately after the chosen one), so totally there are $i$ numbers fixed and we are left with $n-i$ numbers to permute.

For example, if $S$ is the $5$-permutation set of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $i = 2$, and in the first part of the formula we choose $2$ and $4$, then we are essentially permuting the numbers $\{1, 2, 4\}$ since $3$ and $5$ have their position fixed. They must come immediately after $2$ and $4$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that 3 is "pegged" to 2 and 5 is "pegged" to 4, so we only need to permutate 1, 2 and 4. But what if we chose 2 and 3 instead of 2 and 4?

Comment: It is the same thing. If we choose 2 and 3, then the position of 3 and 4 becomes fixed and we are permuting 1,2 and 5. You cannot think of it as "pegged into" because the numbers are still there, 3 does not disappear, it is just the position becoming fixed. The example I give is probably a bit confusing, we permute 1, 2, 4 in the example because 3 and 5 is fixed, not because 2 and 4 are the chosen number. Note that 1 is not chosen and needs to be permuted.

Comment: I understand it more clearly now, although I must admit I'm still a little confused. Thank you for your response. I will accept your answer if no better answers come along.

Comment: It makes more sense to me when I think of it this way: when I choose $i$ properties, I am fixing $i$ elements *with respect to* the remaining $n - i$ elements. So all that remains is to permutate the remaining $n - i$ elements. Of course, all these is what you mentioned originally.

Comment: Sure, if you wish to fix the elements you choose with respect to the element that comes after it, everything is totally fine as well. The key part is that there must be exactly i elements fixed.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, my "pegged into" analogy is still applicable, for example, if we chose 2 and 3, then 4 is "pegged" to 3 and 3 is in turn "pegged" to 2, so we permutate the remaining "unpegged" elements 1, 2 and 5. But I agree that the main idea is that there are exactly $n - i$ elements that are volatile and need to be permutated.